# D3 Histogram - Date Based

Tags: date, d3.js, scale, histogram

I have an array of dates

```
["01/01/2001", "01/01/2001", "03/01/2001", "01/04/2001", "01/05/2001", "02/05/2001", "01/07/2001", "01/07/2001", "01/07/2001", "01/10/2001"]
```

Some are duplicates and in no particular order, over a  varying timescale (1 week, 43 days, 2 years etc).

What I want to do is produce a histogram (or bar chart) that shows counts of "dates" in arbitrary # of buckets (like 20 buckets).

Where there are no dates in a bucket it shows zero and a total for those buckets that contain dates.

Basically like this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450

But instead of showing random "seconds" I need "dates".

Like:

[image: Histogram of dates]

I guess I'm looking to change X scale domain to the range of dates in my data.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a very vague question -- please update with the specific issues that you're struggling with.

Comment: Specifically, what would I need to change in this example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450) to accept an array of "dates" rather than "minutes"

Comment: It sounds like all you would need to do is change the formatter for the x axis ticks to take a date, parse it and then format it as you want it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the solution for this is as @LarsKotthoff suggested in the comments.

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([firstDate, lastDate]).range([0, width]);

var data = d3.layout.histogram()
        .bins(x.ticks(bins))  
        (values);

var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%y");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(formatDate);
```

Comment: Could you please paste the full code you used to solve this issue? it's not readily clear what variables you previously defined before generating your histogram. Thanks!

Comment: I found calculating the width of the bars a little bid odd, because in the data array that the histogram layout generates the `x` value is a date but the `dx` value is a number of milliseconds. For the width of a bar, I used: `x(new Date(data[0].x.getTime() + data[0].dx))`

Comment: This code is incomplete. How did you compute the bins?